# Maximum Infowindow width size without scroll in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My markers have a content of images, but after a >600px in width Google Maps automatically add a horizontal scroll in the infowindow..what is the maximum size of infowindow in Google Maps V3? if possible how can extend the maximum size?

I dont need much more than 650/700px..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without seeing your code, but it sounds like you may have placed your image within a DOM element that has a smaller width than the image? If you add the code you are using to define your info-window, your info-window-options, and your content to your question, it will be easier for others to give you more specific suggestions.

By default, an `InfoWindow`[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows) is sized based on its content, which may be: text, HTML, or a DOM element. The best way to control the `width` of an `InfoWindow` is to place the content within a `div` and define a CSS style rule that explicitly defines a `width` for the `div`. When using the default sizing based on the size of the content, the maximum width of an `InfoWindow` is only limited by the width of your Map.

Your other option is the `maxWidth` property (measured in pixels) of the `InfoWindowOptions`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions) object, which may be associated with an `InfoWindow`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) by passing the  options object to the info-window's constructor or by calling the `InfoWindow.setOptions` function after the info-window has been created. The `InfoWindowOptions.maxWidth` property will only be used if the options object has been associated with an info-window prior to calling the `InfoWindow.open` function. If you have a use case that requires you to change the value of `maxWidth` when you are changing the info-window's content, you must:

1. Call `InfoWindow.close`
2. Call `InfoWindow.setOptions` (passing in an `InfoWindowOptions` object with the new `maxWidth` value)
3. Call `InfoWindow.setContent`
4. Call `InfoWindow.open` to display the info-window on the Map

The Google Maps Developer's Guide includes an: [example Map with the info-window maxWidth value set to 200 pixels](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max). You may want to check that out if you are interested in using the `maxWidth` option and would like to explore a working Map that uses that option.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer Sean Mickey.

Like you said Google Maps automatically sets the maxWidth InfoWindow according to the size of map, in my case is just too small, after a lot of digging i did found two ways to bypass this, using customs infoWindows:

- InfoBox.
  http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html
  A bit complex to implement but it works.
- infoBubble.
  http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/
  Very simple to implement.

I´m using infoBubble, fits perfectly for my needs.

Thanks.